# Swift for iOS development in Win 8

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, swift

I want to develop iOS application with swift in windows 8.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need for iOS application development is xCode and xCode can not run into windows so simply it is not possible to develop an iOS application with windows pc but there is many ways to run mac OS into windows OS.

One way is you can download [mac os x 10.9 vmware preinstalled](http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-use-os-x-10-9-vmware-image-windows-8-windows) copy from the internet and if you follow the step by step installation you can simply run a mac os to your windows pc.

After that you can download xCode and you can start developing an iOS application and lot more.

But one disadvantage of this is it will be slow compare to real mac.

May be this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**No you cannot develop iOS application on windows 8**.

You must have mac os in your machine for application development.