# Starting with SWIFT Programming

Tags: swift

I am new to IOS applications development using SWIFT Programming. Are there any alternate software's or applications which can be used on a Windows laptop to code using Swift? I dont have a Mac system.

Comment: If you just want to get your hands on Swift (without any of the iOS frameworks of course...) you could try [IBM's online repl](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl)

Comment: Swift has become open source so you can try http://elementscompiler.com/elements/silver/ and https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl

Comment: Don't confuse Swift with iOS development. Swift is only a language. It also works on Linux, for example. But to develop *iOS apps* with Swift, you need a Mac. Swift is an open-source language made by Apple but not limited to Apple platforms. On the other hand, to make iOS and macOS apps you need to do that on a Mac.

Comment: With regard to iOS development on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076574/swift-for-ios-development-in-win-8, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine.

Comment: Yes if you have a good cpu you can run OS Sierra for example in VMWare. Works fine for me, but there is no way you can develop SpriteKit games in that.

Comment: Eric - I have a certification in swift programming so i am pretty much aware that its coding language. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need OSX to write iOS apps. There are ways to run OSX on a Windows PC but they are against the OSX EULA.

Comment: Remember: The *Mac OS X* is renamed and branded as the *macOS*

Comment: @Mannopson Only for 10.12+ (starting with Sierra). It is not retroactive, Apple explained this: the OS names before 10.12 aren't impacted by this change. :)